# Prevent "with" binding from removing DOM elements (Knockout.js)

Tags: dom, knockout.js

Knockouters,

I have come to rely on the with binding for establishing context nesting. while I like the way KO manipulates the DOM based on the state of the bound elements in some instances, sometime I just want the binding implications without the DOM removal.

Does anyone know if it is possible way to prevent the DOM manipulation on an individual element binding level?

Thanks,
Vinney

Comment: What version of the Knockout you have? It should be fixed in 2.2

Comment: Indeed, I have 2.1.0. I'll look into an update. However, can you expand on what "fixed" means? An added config/parameter? Also, please respond as an answer so that I may accept your answer if appropriate.

Comment: @Slawek I was a bit confused by your comment. I came away thinking that the actual DOM manipulation was a Knockout bug. Although, the documentation states otherwise. So what does "fixed" mean? Was there some instance where the DOM manipulation was actually happening errantly? If so, can you please explain? My object was non-null however, all it's contained members were null. Should this have triggered the removal of the associated elements? Thanks!

Comment: please look at KO 2.2 release notes - other improvemnts: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/

Comment: Thanks @Sławek! This is exactly what I was looking for on the official site and GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 2.2+ of Knockout won't clear the DOM element when `with` is bound initially to an object (or other truthy value). Alternatively, you can use the `withlight` binding that I put together some time ago. It only will bind to an object (not an observable).

```
ko.bindingHandlers['withlight'] = {
    'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var bindingValue = valueAccessor();
        if (typeof bindingValue != 'object' || bindingValue === null)
            throw new Error('withlight must be used with an object');
        var innerContext = bindingContext['createChildContext'](bindingValue);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Interesting binding handler. I'm curious to know what problem you were solving with this... Care to explain?

Comment: I wanted a binding that only did a context change without any templating features. So that's what it is.

Comment: I see. But what your view functionality is dictating your model. Did you consider allowing for an observable object and unwrapping it to achieve the same result? I'm not trying to challenge your design but rather understand what considerations I'm missing in my own.

Comment: Supporting observables generally means using the template model (DOM manipulation), although I've worked around that in my [Knockout fork](https://github.com/mbest/knockout) by supporting observable child view models.

Comment: "Version 2.2+ of Knockout won't clear the DOM element when with is bound initially to an object" I am using 3.4.2 and its clearing my dom elements and creating them again, my change/blur/keydown/paste events are deleted using the **with** binding.

Comment: @ShadowKras If you think there's a problem with Knockout, please open a new issue at https://github.com/knockout/knockout

Comment: I was just pointing out that the statement is no longer true. jquery events are removed after binding elements to knockout on current versions.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2315), though, I suspect its something on my setup. All issues related to similar problems are over 3 years old.